# Erro de ordenação em relatório ReportBuilder

Tags: sql, classificação, delphi-7, report-builder

Em um relatório construído no ReportBuilder do Delphi7 tenho as informações do fornecedor em um group header e os itens desse fornecedor em uma aba detail logo abaixo. O problema é que não está sendo possível ordenar os itens (detail) conforme parâmetro ('C' código ou 'D' descrição)

Mais informações:

Os dados do relatório vem de uma procedure e a ordenação é feita direto no DataSet do objeto desse relatório no Delphi. Ou seja, eu tenho uma procedure que monta todo o sql onde são puxados os dados que serão exibidos enquanto que na IDE o componente DataSet tem no seu código sql o order by que deveria ordenar o cabeçalho por ordem alfabética e os itens de acordo com o parâmetro.

ex: com parâmetro de ordenação 'C' código, ou seja itens ordenados por código

```
FORNECEDOR A
item 1 "B"
item 2 "A"
item 3 "C"

FORNECEDOR B
item 1 "B"
item 2 "A"
```

- Se altero o parâmetro para 'D'  o resultado continua o mesmo quando o esperado era:

  FORNECEDOR A
  item 2 "A"
  item 1 "B"
  item 3 "C"

  FORNECEDOR B
  item 2 "A"
  item 1 "B"

no `dataset`, obviamente fica:

```
    select (dados) from procedure as alias 
order by (campo do titulo do fornecedor, 
case par_ordenacao
 when 'C' codigo when 'D' 
descrição end
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta dessa forma:

```
case
    when par_ordenacao = 'C' then codigo
    when par_ordenacao = 'D' then descricao end asc
```

Comment: Infelizmente aqui não foi possível executar o relatório acrescentando o "asc". Não sei dizer ao certo o que foi. A principio o que você falou parece ser uma possibilidade. Erro: SQLDA missing or incorrect version, or incorrect number/types of variables

Comment: Está usando qual versão do sql?

Comment: Obs: O problema ocorre mesmo se escolho "Descrição" ('D') para ordenar o item.

Comment: Sim sim, naturalmente se fizermos uma funcionar a outra funcionará de acordo. Seu sql é o ansi mesmo?

Comment: Sobre a versão do Sql, a principio aqui eu uso IBExpert 2014. Obs 2: Testei também por o "asc" antes mas apresenta erro também

Comment: E removendo ele, visto que asc é o padrão..

Comment: Sim, mas se remover o asc dai a gente volta pra estaca zero, pq dai o código fica como tava antes.